# Agregar estilo a un codigo en php de mi web

Tags: php, style, estilos

estoy trancada con un código el cual muestra el nombre del país de mis usuarios en mi página web. Quiero darle estilo, que tenga una fuente más pequeña, pero no me queda cuando agrego el class. El código es el siguiente:

```
<p> <?php $country = $og['user_profile']['country_id']; if ($country > 0) { ?>
<?php echo $og['countries_name'][$country];?></p> 
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: "pero no me queda cuando agrego el class". No veo la clase por ningún lado. Debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar todo el código.

Comment: Lo sé, es que no la agregue porque no se donde va. Cuando la agregue después del <p> class="estilo2" no hacía nada.

Comment: Por lo que cuentas, es posible que la clase `estilo2` no este correctamente definida en el html. Puedes probar agregando directamente el estilo de la forma `<p style="font-size: 10px;"></p>`

Comment: Bien, entiendo que quedaria asi: <p style="font-size: 10px;" <?php $country = $og['user_profile']['country_id']; if ($country > 0) { ?>
<?php echo $og['countries_name'][$country];?></p> 
</li>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Esta bien como lo coloque arriba? Es correcto?

Comment: No funciona agregando style="font-size: 10px;" alguien me puede ayudar

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque el CSS te da problemas.

La estructura sería algo como

```
<?php
    $country = "España";

    $info = "Otra cosa desde PHP";

    $html = '<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Web Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .h1{
                color: red;
                size: 25px;
            }
            .otraClase{
                background-color: teal;
            }
            .link{
                font-style: none;
                color: green;
            }
            .link:hover{
                background-color: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="h1"><?php echo $country; ?></h1>
        <p class="otraClase"><?php echo $info; ?></p>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

El resultado es este, obvio sin PHP porque esta función de SOes no trabaja con PHP.

```css
.h1{
                color: red;
                size: 25px;
            }
            .otraClase{
                background-color: teal;
            }
            .link{
                font-style: none;
                color: green;
            }
            .link:hover{
                background-color: pink;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Web Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="h1">España</h1>
        <p class="otraClase">Otra cosa desde PHP</p>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

En mi ambiente funciona perfectamente.

---

Acá no se puede usar PHP pero te paso captura del PHP fiddle con el siguiente código

```
<?php
    echo $html = '<a href="#" style="color:red; font-size: 100px;background-color:teal;">SI FUNCIONA !!!</a>';
?>
```

Resultado
[image: php]

Vuelvo y repito, algo malo tienes, esto es PHP puro y el estilo no depende que se imprima desde PHP (cosa que es un error)...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta... ahí está el tema, lo mío es php, no html. Por eso no funciona style="font-size: 10px;" dentro de  <p  </p>

Comment: Pero si es lo mismo, el navegador colocará el estilo que tu le des con PHP. Voy a poner otro ejemplo de **CSS inline** desde PHP.

Comment: Siiii me funcionó, muchas gracias OCHO!!

Comment: @GabrielaQuinteros si he resuelto tu duda marca la pregunta como resuelta para que otros en el futuro se puedan guiar también. Gracias